# Change Topbar of Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, top-link-bar, top-navigation

Is it possible to remove or change the topbar Links which seen under number 1 and number 2 in the picture?

I do not like that the users come to the www.office.com Page (the link behind number 1) and also not like that they open the 9 dots (number 2) if they don't have an Office365 licence.

Most users would open this only as registered users, but not with a fully office265 licence.

Thanks for any tip.

We like to use SharePoint online.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use CSS style to hide it.

```
<style>
a[href*='www.office.com']{
    display:none !important;
}
#O365_MainLink_NavMenu{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```